# How to customize datatable to move the pagination info

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any way to move the pagination info like "Show entries" in place of search box by removing the search box. Also I need to move another pagination info like "showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries" to the left side of "show entries".I have shown this in the attached image.

My fiddle is here at http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/56d1t0jt/.

## Html

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data2</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

[image: details_to_move_pagination_info_shown_HERE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for, is the [sDom option](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom). This allows you to show or hide specific fields, and to determine where and in what order they are shown:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable({"sDom": '<"H"ilr><"clear">t<"F"p>' });
});
```

`<"H"ilr>` means that the `i`(information), `l`(length changing) and `r`(processing) should be in the header.

`<"clear">` means that an HTML element with the class `clear` is placed there. (otherwise the table is misplaced). Then the `t` is the actual table, and after that the `<"F"p>` means that the `p` (pagination) is placed in the footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/56d1t0jt/2/

I also added some CSS, to align the "Show * entries" to the right properly.

```css
#myTable_length {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can read "sDom": '<"H"ilr><"clear">t<"F"p>'

Comment: okay....Is there any chance not to come the information like "Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries".I mean any configuration to be done to show/hide this information. I used <"H"ilr> but its not showing that information for me

Comment: I used sDom like - "sDom": "<'H'ilr<'transPdfWrapper pdfWrapper left'>'<'transExcelWrapper excelWrapper left'>>t". This is not giving me the "Showing......."

Comment: It does when I use it [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56d1t0jt/3/). Parhaps your transPdfWrapper or transExcelWrapper divs push it away.

Comment: ya...I got it...the class "dataTables_info" has the visibility hidden. Bcz of this that information was not visible.Is there any way to customize this class

Comment: You can just change the css to visible. Something like `.dataTables_info { visibility: visible; }`

Comment: In some places its visibility should be hidden.so I cannot change the class like that bcz it will affect all other places. Is there any other way to make this visible in a single(particular) place.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case you can simply add a class to the table where it should be visible. If you add the class `visible_entity_count` to your table, then you can use something like this: `.visible_entity_count .dataTables_info { visibility: visible; }`